# Proof review - All natural numbers can be written as unique product of primes.

Tags: proof-verification, induction

P(n): All natural numbers greater than 1 can be expressed as a unique product of primes where order doesn't matter.

By strong induction:

Base Case n=2: 2=2*1 so base case holds as this is a unique prime representation.

Inductive step: Assume, for purposes of induction, that P(n) holds for all natural numbers up to n i.e. 2,3,4...n.

Now take the number n+1.

If n+1 is prime, it has a unique representation (by definition of being prime) and we are done.

If it is composite, it can be written as a product of natural numbers (not necessarily unique or prime) all of which are smaller than n+1.
 - but we know from IHOP that all numbers up to n have unique prime representations
 - so we can replace all the numbers forming n+1 by their unique representations (as given by IHOP)
 - hence, all possible representations of n+1 will reduce to the same unique product of primes after substituting.

Hence, by principle of mathematical induction, the P(n) holds for all natural numbers.

Comment: What's IHOP? $\;\!$

Comment: " I hope" it's induction hypothesis

Comment: Is there an IHOP out there that has math scribbled on the walls? :]

Comment: Induction Hypothesis. In this case: all natural numbers from 2 to n can be written as a unique product of primes. Also, what was that about math scribbled on walls again?

Comment: Works for representability as a product of primes, but not for uniqueness.

Comment: Why do we know that $n+1$ being composite, and its factors having a unique representation, that it too has a unique representation?  $n+1$ being composite implies that it can be written as $a\cdot b$ with $a$ and $b$ not equal to $1$.  That does not prevent it from also being equal to $c\cdot d$, with $c,d$ different than $a,b$.  What is to say that the concatenation of the representations of $a,b$ will be the same as the concatenation of the representations of $c,d$?  This is not proven in your proof, and therefore your proof is incomplete.

Comment: Your base case appears to be under the false impression that 1 is a prime. It ain't.

Comment: It seems to me, based on the comments (although I'll admit this proof seems very suspect as being "too simple") that what you are lacking is a proof that given $a\cdot b = c\cdot d$ that these both give unique prime factorizations (one should not need the caveat that none are equal to $1$ in my opinion since this should work for $1\cdot 1 = 1\cdot 1$ as well and I would argue any proof requiring such is incomplete).

Comment: @Joffan I don't think that matters since 2 is a prime (and has unique representation by definition of being prime) so you could just write the base as 2=2.

Comment: I think @JMoravitz and @Jared you guys are on the right track. Maybe I should have added a lemma that any representations we get by substituting the composites in any representation of `n+1` by their unique prime factors. I had thought it might be 'obvious'.

Comment: @Jared you can't have any equal to $1$ because otherwise the other is equal to $n+1$ and the induction hypothesis says nothing about that case. @ Warrshrike, The major steps for uniqueness yet to show:  assuming $(n+1)=a\cdot b = c\cdot d$ and $a,b,c,d$ all have unique decompositions: $a=a_1\cdot a_2\cdots a_i, b=b_1\cdot b_2\cdots b_j, c=c_1\cdot c_2\cdots c_k, d=d_1\cdot d_2\cdots d_l$ you have $(n+1)=a_1\cdots a_i b_1\cdots b_j = c_1\cdots c_k d_1\cdots d_l$.  First, why is $i+j=k+l$?  Why is $a_1$ one of $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_k,d_1,\dots,d_l$?

Comment: Why then is the multiset $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_i,b_1,b_2,\dots,b_j\}$ equal to the multiset $\{c_1,\dots,c_k,d_1,\dots,d_l\}$?

Comment: As a final comment before I go to bed, a proof appears on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).  (*Keep working on it on your own without reading it if you like*).  What you have shown is equivalent to the *existence* portion of the proof, but the *uniqueness* portion has yet to be completed.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JMoravitz. Yeah my rationale had been that if I added uniqueness to the induction hypothesis, I could do it in one go rather than the usual two part proof for the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. Clearly the result was incomplete.